# Android scale a RelativeLayout with an ImageView inside

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, scale, android-custom-view

I have a RelativeLayout with an ImageView (with match_parent as height and width). The ImageView has a scaleType of center_crop.

I programatically scale the RelativeLayout in the Y axis according to a specific gesture on the device. The RelativeLayout scales correctly, but the ImageView stretches instead of center_crops as expected. I assume this is because the ImageView is only centered and cropped in the start during the layout process. Is there anyway I can force the ImageView to recalculate the center_cropping process while the gesture is in motion?

I will appreciate any help. I can post more information and examples if my question isn't making any sense.

Comment: Have you tried `imageView.invalidate()`?

Comment: @Lamorak yea I tried that with no luck. I managed to solve it though. I ended up giving the relative layout new layout parameters of a larger height rather than scaling it. Will make an answer if someone doesn't find a better way.